# The abundance of which material would provide the most improvement to world economy?

Tags: science-based, economy

The World has just received an official communication: on December the 21st 2022 we will receive a special visit.

Techno Mage Master Balmelgas will be visiting Earth on his wonder ship Sol Invictus.
His purpose: to adopt a Rose.

In exchange he will give to the World one material we may need. Just one but in any quantity we may choose.
His powers are unfathomable. He may raise sea levels by 100 meters, make a mountain chain made of solid gold in the Sahara desert or a ring of diamonds around the largest city.

World leaders, in a rare moment of enlighment, have decided to collaborate and ask something that will benefit mankind as a whole. Specifically the request must be thus that world economy has the best possible improvement. Benefits are going to be distributed to everyone.
The problem is Governments are at a loss about what to ask.
Can the wise people at Stack Exchange help?
**What material would provide the most improvement to world economy?**

Conditions:

- a small sample of the material must be provided by World governments so that it can be replicated in the required quantity. No Unobtanium.
- the material must be simple. It can be a metal, a molecule, a polymer but no more that 3 elements in it. E.g. the molecule of Methane CH4 or Glucose C6H12O6 are admitted. Ammonium acetate NH4CH3CO2 is not.
- delivery will be agreed upon so that no accidents may happen.
- World governments will have to provide containment to the material, if needed. E.g. it 's fine to ask for 1000 tons of Plutonium. Delivered material will be beamed directly in containment cells all over the world if such is the request. But the containment of the material must not become too much of an economic burden.
- Effects on world economy must be considered. Specifically the law of offer and demand. Would the abundance of the material make it worthless? Or would the boost in economy be such that demand would stay high?
- Redistribution of the generated wealth is not a concern in choosing the material. Let's just assume that global economic gains are going to be accounted for and equally redistributed.
- only a material will be provided, not any specific structure made of that material. E.g. no space elevator magically appearing in place. The Mage provides the material but the hard work is up to us.
- Techno Mage Master Balmelgas will leave by January the 6th 2023. By then all the required material will be delivered. This means that something like a river that will keep flowing after the 6th of January is not a feasible request.

Please specify how the choosen material would improve world economy.
If possible (not strictly required) specify quantity to require. If not specified Governments are just going to ask for A LOT of it, as much as reasonably possible.

** Bounty will be added when eligible **

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140724/discussion-on-question-by-duncan-drake-the-abundance-of-which-material-would-pro).

Comment: Does "improve the world economy" have a time horizon? Tomorrow, next year, in the lifetime of our children, in the next few thousand years?

Comment: @gs Given that governments are involved I expect they would want to start seeing improvements in a limited timeframe, potentially building up more in the future. They would certainly not care for an improvement that will be usable hundreds of years in the future. They never did. Still governments are trying to take action against climate change now even if the worse of it may happen in about 50 years from now. So in short: "within the lifetime of our children, the sooner, the better".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Get Balmelgas to do some geoengineering for us.

Foresterite (Mg<sub>2</sub>SiO<sub>4</sub>) is a type of [olivine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivine), a class of minerals that are particularly reactive with atmospheric carbon dioxide.  Mining and dispersal of olivines has been proposed as a potential method for [accelerated weathering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_weathering), to increase the rate at which natural geological processes draw carbon dioxide out of the atmosphere.  Having it in a fine-grained form, spread over much of the Earth's surface, would accelerate the rate at which atmospheric carbon dioxide would react with the mineral.

At a sufficient scale, dispersing this mineral (or another olivine) over Earth's surface could allow us to slow and perhaps even reverse climate change.  And it hardly needs to be said that if we could reverse climate change, it would have huge beneficial effects on the global economy.

So the request would be, more or less:

> Here is a sample of powdered forsterite.  Please provide us with about a trillion tons [exact amount TBD] of this material in this form, spread in a uniform layer over Earth's surface.  Maybe don't put any on the more populated areas, though.  And dump some in the oceans too, that'll help with acidification we've caused.

**Addition**
This [article](https://eos.org/editors-vox/preventing-climate-change-by-increasing-ocean-alkalinity) provides additional details on the method. It focuses on altering the alkalinity of the oceans but the idea is the same.
[Here the scientific papers](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/2016RG000533)

Comment: A quadrillion tonnes is probably too much. Given: the density of forsterite, a packing fraction of 0.4 (typical value for uniform powders of around 10um in particle size), and about 50% of the land surface of earth being uninhabited, you'd bury all that land to a depth of about 11.5m in finely powdered forsterite. Really we need to remove about 10Gt CO2/yr to ameliorate the worst of climate change, which would "only" require about 10B tonnes per year that we need to do this, so call it 100 years or "only" about a trillion tonnes.  That much powder would be ~1cm deep given the same assumptions.

Comment: @realityChemist:  Thanks for the order-of-magnitude check!  I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Do you have any idea of the time scale of the chemical reaction? Could you provide an order of magnitude to decrease CO2 in a significant way? I could not fint in the linked article. What if the olivine dust were to be spread in the stratosphere too?

Comment: @DuncanDrake:  I honestly don't know.  The place I would look is [this National Academies of Science report](https://nap.nationalacademies.org/catalog/25259/negative-emissions-technologies-and-reliable-sequestration-a-research-agenda) but the site is not responding just now.  I'll try to remember to check again later this weekend and see what I can figure out.

Comment: If we wanted to do that, we could just add iron nanoparticles to the antarctic ocean. It's been know for decades that such an. addition would spark massive CO2 capture in a short time frame. The problem, as always, would be that humans would take it as free license to produce enough CO2 to compensate.

Comment: Well done. Balmelgas is pleased ^.^

Answer (score 46):

If the goal was to have benefits to the ecology or quality of life of humanity, I'd say Lithium or some other battery input that would reduce strategic resource scarcities in renewable energy-enabling technologies like grid-scale energy storage.

But if you want to just drive the global GDP I'd say steel.  Specifically, 1 megaton of steel delivered to 35,786km above mean sea level, with velocity at delivery of 11,300 km/hr. In other words: 1 million tons of steel delivered to geosynchronous orbit.

That takes the cost of constructing an orbital ring around the Earth from trillions of dollars to maybe a billion or two. It would require the launch of fabrication equipment, but since the main cost of doing anything in space is in the launch costs of getting mass up there, having a million tons of basic steel already in orbit means we can focus on launching high-value-per-kg stuff instead.

Once the orbital ring is in place, the resource base that world industry can work with is powerfully extended well beyond the Earth itself.  This will likely drive several major learning processes which further reduce the costs of moving material to and from orbit.

We have the necessary technologies already - it's just the cost of bootstrapping that's preventing us from doing it.

Comment: Why not copper? Steel displaced copper for many things simply because it was more abundant and cheaper, not necessarily superior in properties or workability. Similarly, cobalt is surprisingly similar to steel and superior in other ways but is expensive and therefore not used often. But when used is used in large amounts the same way iron is for steel.

Comment: Only problem with steel is that you'd only get one alloying element besides carbon.  No chromoly steels, most stainless ones are out...

Comment: There's a few more problems with the steel idea. Like that one Megaton isn't nearly enough. A Yamato class Battleship displaces ~70.000 tons, at a length of some 260m. 1 Million tons of steel is around 14 Yamatos, end-to-end that's about 3,6km worth of steel train. Not quite enough to go around the earth. Granted, you can skimp a little on the armor plating of your orbital ring, but even with the most optimistic of planning you're not going to stretch that amount of steel around the globe, and most definitely not for 1-2 Billion dollars. It's a novel idea, though.

Comment: How is the mass of steel going to maintain orbit? We don't want a giant steel asteroid impact at some point in the future should we be unable to make use of it in time

Comment: @matt_rule Like the Moon, in order to make that megaton change orbit it'll need to get impacted very hard. There is less atmospheric pressure at that height than solar wind, therefore there is no actual possibility other than an unexpected collision of a passerby asteroid that can alter that steel's orbit enough to drop it on the surface.

Comment: @DKNguyen: Copper is way too soft. Titanium, Aluminium or Magnesium might be more useful. Stiffer per ton than steel, and you get to pick 2 elements for use in alloys.

Comment: @MSalters Pure aluminum is just as soft. I imagine when you speak here you are comparing pure copper to aluminum alloys which are also often just called aluminum. But, while pure aluminum has few uses and is extremely abundant in Earth's crust (even more than iron), pure copper has even more uses and is more than 1000 times rarer. 8% vs 0.007%. Mechanical applications are not the only applications and copper is not easily substituted in those. Magnesium is very high up there in abundance (2%).

Comment: @DKNguyen: This answer focuses on an orbital ring - it cheats on the premise of the question by having the material delivered in orbit, where it's way more valuable. That's why it doesn't matter that we have an abundance of Aluminium on the surface. And there the mass of the ring itself matters; Aluminium wins mostly because it's 3 times less dense.

Comment: @MSalters Oh you are speaking about it from the orbital context. I was not. I imagine in that context you might be able to use gold-platinum or some structural gold or platinum alloy of there are any. You know, something that just isn't used due to lack of quantity. It seems as far as gold is concerned though there have been extensive investigations with little success regarding strength. More success in hardness though.

Comment: Aluminum would be a better option than steel, it is harder to extract from common rocks and soil, but cheaper to process and transport once you have it due to its lower melting point and density while being just as able to fulfill a wide range of structural needs.

Comment: All of this discussion on the merits of different metals misses the point that a metal ring in orbit, *without life support, power, or machinery of any sort*, is completely worthless. You can't live on it, build on it, or use it for any industrial purpose.

Comment: Is an orbital ring in geostationary orbit really that helpful? I thought the usual place would be in low earth orbit (maybe 400 km), so you can put ropes/tethers down to pull things up.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann see, at 400 km orbit the ring will suffer atmospheric friction causing it to slow down, also you want a solid ring in order to be able to lift something up to it via ropes, otherwise the ring will split and parts of it will crash to the surface causing quite a megaton of damage. And asking the wizard to provide a solid ring the size of planet is prohibited by the requirement of providing a small sample which then would be replicated.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking of the actively stabilized one, which doesn't rotate on its own, but has magnetically channeled orbital (or super-orbital) things holding it up, which can be accelerated magnetically. But I guess you can't set this up via such a wish. Still I doubt a ring on geostationary heights is actually useful – to get up there you still need your space elevator tech.

Answer (score 31):

The million-tons-of-steel-in-orbit suggestion has merit, but can be optimised.  The most valuable things to have in space are something to build with, something to breathe, and something to burn for fuel, and there are plenty of simple compounds that can contribute to all three. I propose a gigaton (because go big or go home) of [titanium hydroxide](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Titanium-hydroxide) $\mathrm{TiH_2O_2}$ (or $\mathrm{TiH_4O_4}$, the internet seems to be conflicted about whether it's $\mathrm{Ti^{2+}}$ or $\mathrm{Ti^{4+}}$) delivered to geosynchronous orbit.  Titanium is at least as good as steel for construction, and for every ton of building material we also get 360kg of water *and* 320kg of oxygen, perfect for orbital life support and rocket fuel production.

Since we'll be going all-out-no-expense-spared in the preparation of the sample, we'll also make sure that the titanium contains a decent proportion of $\mathrm{^{51}Ti}$, which will decay in a few minutes to give us a little bit (ie a few million tons) of vanadium, dope the oxygen with $\mathrm{^{15}O}$ which will decay to nitrogen after 122s, and mix as much tritium into the hydrogen as we can possibly get our hands on, up to a couple of percent.

Comment: While TiH2O2 is acceptable adding isotopes is not. An isotope can have completely different properties from the original element. Asking for isotopes is fine. But each counts as one element.

Comment: Chemically isotopes are almost indistinguishable (with hydrogen/deuterium/tritium being a notable exception), but I agree that it's an attempt to wish the genie for more wishes.  Master Balmelgas will have to decide how pedantic he wishes to be about the naturally-occurring distribution of stable isotopes of the elements in the sample, or whether to insist that the humans present an atomically pure sample to prove their worthiness for the Great Exchange.

Comment: There are issues with doping process, as the wizard is picky with 3 elements per Wish. Let's assume he accepts the thing made of doped TiH2O2 at T=0, but goes for investigation at T=1 day. Surprise, the thing now has Ti, V, N, H, O. Boom, disqualified.

Comment: @Stephen "Do not haggle in the offers of Mages, for they are subtle and quick to anger." Still yours is an ingenious answer and that pleases the Mage. Plus he can't honestly ask for the material to be absolutely pure. I don't believe today's tech is capable of doing that. He is just going to leave the spurious elements out. If we were to give him a glass of water telling him to duplicate the H2O that is what we will have. Not the 1 in 1 million extra molecule. The decayment is a subsequent event, originating from the accepted material. That is accepted. Good thinking.

Comment: TiH2O2 is not a metal, and will have to be processed before being put to use. We don't have systems in place capable of converting that massive amount of ore into titanium in space, on any reasonable timescale. Some alloy of titanium would be better,  even if we'd have to ship up life support systems ourselves.

Comment: You better prepare it in a way so when the sample is duplicated it doesn't cause Kessler syndrome.

Comment: Also there's the issue with the energy relased from the decay, more then a trace concentration here will vaporise the material, not a good idea.

Comment: @DuncanDrake "He is just going to leave the spurious elements out. If we were to give him a glass of water telling him to duplicate the H2O that is what we will have. Not the 1 in 1 million extra molecule." In that case he would purify impure graphene sheets as well....

Comment: @DKNguyen https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/238281/75358 cold welding them into a dyson shpere superstructure sounds like the way to go

Answer (score 18):

## Helium-3

If we were to gamble on our chances to make working fusion reactors. With enough this stuff we could power world cleanly for very long time. And the bonus of Helium-3 fusion compared to others is that it doesn't produce neutrons which irradiate reactors and destroy the walls.

Most common method of fusion currently is fusing isotopes of hydrogen. Deuterium hydrogen with neutron and tritium hydrogen with two neutrons. Deuterium with tritium producing helium, energy and free neutron. This
neutron tends to irradiate things like reactor walls. Weakening them and making them radioactive.

Helium-3 opens two possibilities. Helium-3+Helium-3 reaction producing Helium-4, energy and two protons. Or Helium-3+Deuterium producing Helium-4, energy and two protons. Positive side of those protons is that they can be handled with magnetic containment thus not producing neutron-radiation.

One gram of Helium-3 could produce 164 MWh. With 23845 TWh being total energy consumption of world would require 145.4 tonnes of Helium-3 to cover this for a year. This would require ~1.1 million cubic meters of storage at NTP.

Helium-3 is non-reactive noble gas that does not decay, but the storage might be problem at short notice. It can be pressurised however it can escape this way. Other option is cryogenic compression, but suitable vessels and tanks for that are likely limited in availability or already filled with naturally occurring Helium.

Geological storage, natural gas and other gas storage are likely options if
Mage Master Balmelgas were willing to place it there. So world governments would better start to look into empty salt and such mines that can be sealed.

Other option is just to replace part of atmosphere with it. This however will likely generate quite big losses as it will probably escape relatively fast.

Comment: How will you store it? There are approx. 6 weeks to prepare storage facilities for $^3$He. Note the storage will be for 50 years until a practical fusion reactor may be available ...

Comment: Hm, He-3 is stable and nonreactive. The best storage might actually be to simply dump it into the atmosphere.. like changing the air composition to be 1-2% He-3.
Extracting that should still be viable.

Comment: Like storing any gas. It doesn't have the same issues as hydrogen. So just having big enough pressure vessels if allowed or just simply anything airtight would work.

Comment: @Chieron Wouldn't it just float up to the top of the atmosphere then be stripped away by solar radiation? Like, isn't that the problem we already have with helium resources on Earth - what little exists in the atmosphere is too high up to extract, so we have to rely on whatever helium got stuck underneath impermeable rock while the Earth was forming?

Comment: @Chieron There's a reason we don't have a lot of helium in the atmosphere despite it being stable. It literally just floats away.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes, but not in a timeframe that would be relevant for its use by us. By the time Earth would've lost a noticeable amount the natural way, we would likely be way past that version of fusion so that He-3 is no longer that important. The comment about reactivity was aimed more at it not being dangerous - we would not poison ourselves.

Comment: @Chieron How quickly does Helium float away? Helium balloons move quite quickly and in this case, it doesn't need to actually float away, just move high enough where it cannot be recaptured.

Comment: Can you add further details to your answer? Could current gas reservoirs contain it? Does it need special conditions to be stored? Has any fusion experiment been done using Helium-3? I found this article: https://www.explainingthefuture.com/helium3.html  may be worth adding. Please expand.

Comment: Additional: looks like Belmelgas already worked on this: :P   https://www.vice.com/en/article/7kbndq/scientists-discover-unexplained-abundance-of-rare-nuclear-fusion-fuel-on-earth      "The inferred 3He change is more than 10x the natural geological fluxes,"

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica couldn't it be stored in undergroud cavities?

Comment: @Ekaros in fact Helium is harder to contain than hydrogen, because it does not form molecules. So the walls of whatever container would eventually be helium-infused as well, and start leaking helium.

Comment: @DuncanDrake: In principle, yes, but we need "free" underground cavities for that. IN Europe there aren't any, suitable underground cavities act as reservervoirs for natural gas and are currently filled (they will empty over winter, but by X-mas there won't be a lot of capacitiy already freed).

Comment: @Vesper For above ground storage that is certainly a problem. With underground, couldn't we eventually just break up the walls and process the stuff? 
In general I think storage is not very feasible. At least in quantities we would require for even medium term.

Comment: @Ekaros Indeed underground storage might not leak too much over 50 years due to sheer thickness of its walls. Yet we have no ready-made underground storage for these, unless we employ existing vaults that are now used for natural gas... could do in fact, but where do we put that methane? Use as energy? OK but what then? Winter is still coming.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica there are a lot of unused mines though. In my area alone i could name 12. They are simply not profitable to exploit anymore.

Comment: Well, what effort would be needed to make them contain some gas? The natural state of abandoned mines is that they are filling up with water.

Answer (score 16):

**Water.**

/Delivered material will be beamed directly in containment cells all over the world if such is the request./

Fresh water will be delivered all over the world.  Lakes and reservoirs will all be topped up.  Dry lake beds and inland depressions (e.g. Lake Eyre, Lake Sahara, Lake Death Valley, Aral Sea) will be converted to lakes.  Ice and lots of it will be deposited atop melting glaciers, replenishing and cooling them.  Perhaps a few new glaciers might be deposited in interested hot areas, there to gradually melt in a soothing coolth.  Depleted underground aquifers around the world will be repleted to preindustrial turgidity.

Farms will be green.  Forests will grow.  There will be food.  There will be energy.  There will be soothing coolth.  Plants limited by water scarcity will grow and take up excess CO2, cooling the planet back down.   Plus Balmelgas Water tastes great!  We might need to come up with a different name for it, though.

Yes; water sweet water.  One could make a case that the boost to the economy will only last as long as the new water does, which is true.  But there is no time period listed in the OP.

Comment: Fata Morgana, Willk... adding water to solve the energy problem will require a continuous supply and in the long term result in floods and sealevel rise, imho it's better to provide  Earth with  a very large amount of hydrogen. You'd have the energy (fuel) and same time you can *choose* to make water while you burn it. See my answer I put (before you)

Comment: Hydrogen is squirrley.  No good way to contain large quantities.  And if you let it go it wants to leave for space.    Earth has existing ways to contain truly immense quantities of water.   If you let water go it falls on the ground, splashing wetly.  I know.

Comment: Well Mage Master Balmelgas provided the hydrogen in handy tanks of unobtanium.. ready for use and plenty of stock.. best of both worlds. But never mind, you go ahead flood the planet with water to help the economy..

Comment: @Goodies The question did specify that we humans are responsible for any containment.

Comment: @Draconis But what are the constraints? For example, can we just have one tank and treat it as a bottomless self-refilling tank? Or is it a slowly delivery where we need many tanks? Or is it a one time dump where there is no way we will ever have enough tanks?

Comment: @DKNguyen - one time dump. /Techno Mage Master Balmelgas will leave by January the 6th 2023. By then all the required material will be delivered. /

Comment: @Willk That's a pickle. Not enough time to prepare for a bunch of freshwater let alone hydrogen. Might as well just ask for something like copper, cobalt, or tungsten, or a precious metal purely out of storage ease and the quantity required to be useful. Or one of the more exotic rare metals like iridium or palladium if you're confident you can do something with it if only you had large amounts.

Comment: @Willk confirmed. One time dump but to be agreed upon and over the period of stay of Balmelgas. Delivery may start from 21st of December and go on until 6th of January if such is the request.

Comment: @DkNguyen - the Earth is already set up to receive a bunch of fresh water.  A few tens of trillion tons more of ice on glaciers.  A hundred trillion liters in depleted aquifers.   The same amount for the Aral sea.  There are lots of places on Earth ready to receive some water.

Comment: A megaton of water is not a lot of water. Add a megaton of water behind the hoover dam and you might not even notice.

Comment: @Murphy - I agree.  Puny megaton.   That is why instead of a mere million tons we are requesting several hundred trillion tons total.

Comment: It'll all end up in the sea. bad news for those who live on the sea coast.

Comment: Aquifiers don't really work because those are made of rock saturated with, rather then under ground lakes and rivers with empty space for the water to appear. Global consumption of water is 4 trillion cubic meters a year, dump all that in the ocean and it'll rise by over a centimetre. The extra ice on glaciers isn't going to cool them enough.

Comment: @blademan9999 /The extra ice on glaciers isn't going to cool them enough./  I am glad you brought that up in advance of the delivery.   I was thinking this might directly counter global warming too.   I have been pondering this math but to make that statement you must have already have an idea for it.  What temperature / quantity shall we request for the ice delivered in order to cool them but not too much?  If there is not enough room to show the math in a comment please edit the answer.

Comment: I think you'd just make a big swamp while flooding most cities.

Comment: https://skepticalscience.com/ gives the additional heat.

Comment: You might also increase tectonic activity by redistributing so much mass on such a short time

Answer (score 14):

*Q: "the material must be simple"*

### Hydrogen

An abundance of molecular hydrogen (H2) would allow humanity to solve fossile fuel shortages and climate issues. Lowering energy prices could make the economy boom.

While burning hydrogen, it is quite easy to collect **pure water**. This could allow humanity to solve other issues.. opening new markets, extend   living space on earth for a growing population.

Comment: You know...until people take it for granted and burn so much of it we start cutting into the oxygen supply.

Comment: Hydrogen is difficult to store long term. It tends to leak through the molecular structure of whatever its container is made of.

Comment: The best 'containment vehicle' for storing great quantities of hydrogen is pure water.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Doing that defeats the purpose of hydrogen though which is as a source of fuel.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond see my comment with Willk's answer below.. another issue with water is the volume of it. There would have to be a continuous supply and there's risk of floods when all that water coming out of nowhere remains on the planet. See opening, this Magus could cause a sea level rise of 100 meters. Maybe freezing the water and storing it on land would be an option, but it gets less economic value when you do that, because energy will be needed to melt the ice.

Comment: @Douglas you're right, I imagine the Magus will take care of the packaging of his present :)

Comment: @Goodies The question specifically states that "World governments will have to provide containment to the material, if needed."

Comment: We can't store any where NEAR enough hydrogen to use it as a water supply.

Comment: Cheap and abundant hydrogen has a ton of possibilities. Sadly can't solve all our problems overnight. Even if all engines are magically transformed into tiny lightweight super efficient versions to power whatever they need to power there are road blocks. Oil has a lot of cheap abundant by products we use everywhere. Asphalt and medicine for example. It'll take time to find good (possibly better!) alternatives. Not to mention some countries would suddenly lose heavily in this trade, causing huge instability in politics and economics. I want hydrogen to be so good, but there's much to overcome.

Comment: It seems to me that we have an unfathomably huge supply of hydrogen just one astronomical unit away from us. No containment vessel needed - its own gravity is sufficient.

Answer (score 11):

Is all that granted material has to be delivered to earth?

If it doesn't I could suggest to place a bunch of asteroids made of zillion tons of solid rocket fuel into solar system distributed evenly along a single orbit around sun with highest possible excentricity perpendicular to eclipse and passing nearby all the planets' orbits. It would give an opportunity to travel across solar system relatively slow, but spending little-to-no fuel, just sitting on a piece of rock. When travellers want to visit a planet passing by, they just scratch a little portion of fuel for manuevering.

Comment: That is acceptable. Delivery is not an issue.

Comment: Just mind the costraint of the 3 elements in the question. Remember you would need an oxidizing agent and a reducing agent. Specify more details please.

Comment: @DuncanDrake  Hydrogen and Oxygen work well in Saturn V's and Space Shuttles. Containment tbd.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon am not rejecting the answer. Just asking to add necessary details

Comment: "relatively slow, but spending little-to-no fuel, just sitting on a piece of rock" - this doesn't work the way you think! To get onto the rock you have to already match the same orbit as the rock and then you were already going where you want anyway.

Comment: Why do you want the orbit perpendicular to the ecliptic (I assume that's what you meant)? Any vessel exploring the solar system will be on the ecliptic. Trying to rendezvous with an object in a perpendicular orbital plane is an extremely costly orbital maneuver - why put the "gas station" in one of the most inconvenient orbital configurations possible? @user253751is correct that riding on the rock accomplishes nothing, if you can land on it, you're already headed exactly where it's going anyway. It is useful for refueling, though.

Comment: Also, what *economic* benefit is this providing?

Answer (score 11):

(Inspired by existing answers)

"Dear Techno Mage Master Balmelgas,

"After much conference and debate, we, the *International Commission to Analyze and Request Unlimited Stuff*, have come to an agreement with regards to your offer. In exchange for guardianship of any one rose of your choosing, we request a truly immense quantity of very thin aluminum sheets, delivered in the manner dictated below.

"(1) Please place one million, 200km x 200km, aluminum sheets (designs in Appendix A), into an orbit identical to that of our planet. Each sheet should be facing the sun and equidistant from the others, spaced evenly around the sun.

"(2) Additionally, please place one thousand smaller aluminum sheets into orbit at a radius of half that of our planet. (Designs in Appendix B).

"(3) As a final request, please deliver five billion tons of relatively small aluminum bars (dimensions in Appendix C) to the major manufacturing cities of every country on our planet (cities listed in Appendix D).

"Your assistance in providing (1) what we refer to as a 'Dyson Ring,' (2) a relatively centralized means of controlling each reflector with radiation pressure, and (3) an abundance of material with which we can immediately drive our economy, is very much appreciated. As we enjoy our immediate economic boom, we plan to use excess wealth to drive the creation of one thousand 'reorientation' ships, which will fly to each of the smaller mirrors and begin reorienting them as necessary, allowing us to focus radiation pressure on the corners of the larger reflectors and direct, in turn, their reflections. Although it will take time, please accept our gratitude for launching us into the next stage of civilization.

P.S - Enclosed, please see our sample 1m x 1m sheet of aluminum. If necessary for the terms and conditions for your offer, please replace our request for 1 million 200km x 200km sheets with a request for 40 quadrillion 1m x 1m sheets, delivered in squares of 200km by 200km, with the edges touching. Please replace the smaller sheets at 0.5au with an equivalent delivery specification."

Comment: Not feasible.  "a small sample of the material must be provided by World governments so that it can be replicated in the required quantity." Small sample. In any form you like. Of course 'small' is relative and you can say "a small hill". But that is a sophism. A "small sample" is clearly something that a laboratory could work with. The small sample can't be a 200km x 200km aluminum sheet. The Mage is not doing the work for us. Small sheets? as many as you like :)

Comment: @Duncan A small sample of a mountain of gold is a pebble of gold.

Comment: Then you are going to have pebbles of gold. As many as you wish. But not a solid block of gold as big as Mount Everest.

Comment: Gotcha. :) I'll add an addendum.

Comment: There we go. Cold welding should do the rest. ;)

Comment: Also, I recognize that this is still playing right at the edge of what the Mage offers, but if it's technically within his terms and conditions, I think it would be worth a shot. We'd still have a *lot* of work to do to make this useful!

Comment: "replace our request for 1 million 200km x 200km sheets with a request for 40 quadrillion 1m x 1m sheets, delivered in squares of 200km by 200km, with the edges touching. Please replace the smaller sheets at 0.5au with an equivalent delivery specification". Crafty :) In all honesty I don't think such a request could be refused. I have no idea if that is going to work out for you though.

Comment: What I don't get is, why would you want them in orbit if you can cold weld them into a ring which you do not have to steer against radiation pressure? Furthermore you could actually cold weld more than just plates but actually a structure with those plates by placing them properly. And lastly if you make plates out of two different metals, you have more variety of material available later

Comment: @Felix - Great ideas, in general. What I wanted to avoid was having the gracious mage do too much of the work, and growing disgruntled / having the answer disqualified. Also, I'm a bit confused; what advantage would a solid ring be? Wouldn't that reflect all light back at the sun? Outward radiation pressure will be an interesting issue to solve, in any Dyson structure, to be sure.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I guess the hope with a ring is, that you have to do less work to ensure that the pieces neither fall down into the sun nor fling out away, as it is a solid object. Of course the strength of the material is not infinite, so it would only make that balancing task easier and not take it away entirely. And the entire point of a dyson structure is to capture as much of the suns energy right? So either you absorb (capture it), or reflect it back into the sun. Either way no energy is wasted into space.

Comment: An interesting thing to do with a ring would be: let it orbit the sun a bit faster such that (if it were pieces) it would fling outwards. Since it is held together by tensile strength, the ring would experience a constant acceleration towards the sun. If you make that acceleration 1g, you can walk on the entire ring. So you could start building infrastructure on this ring. Which is why I suggested a few different materials.

Comment: @Felix Gotcha. I think we have different ideas on what we're trying to accomplish with the ring. I pictured the goal, rather than capturing energy directly (as heat), to be able to reroute the energy to where we wanted it. So we can push space probes, eliminate threats, redirect asteroids, energize distant space stations, power a fusion reactor producing nuclear batteries near Earth, etc. But the idea of building a navigable megastructure is also very interesting, and would probably be the long-term result of having a Dyson swarm, such as the one I envisioned.

Answer (score 9):

### Plutonium

Why? We need energy the most, and plutonium in itself is a pretty stable thing to have around, even with high gamma emission the expected "megaton" would produce. With enough plutonium, nuclear stations would provide enough energy to top off "green" and fossil fuels burn, allowing the humanity to avert energetic crisis for a good thousand years. (Of course nuclear waste processing would be required to handle all the mass of nuclear isotopes produces in power plants, but this is a slightly different story) Also increasing mutation frequency all around the world can *eventually* benefit humans as a whole, at the cost of innumerable deaths over immeasurable time, yet we already are undergoing induced evolution, so having it *slightly* accelerated could indeed prove beneficial.

**Otherwise...**

Currently, the economy is somewhat balanced, and anything provided will tip at least some scales, or can even turn some over. Say, if asked for lithium or rather palladium, the market for such a metal will be ruined, with collapsing production and shockwaves across neighboring markets. And regardless of commodity, eventually this supply would run out, whether it would take a year or a thousand years to exhaust it, it would still be a single fixed influx, thus another upheaval would happen once this supply would be exhausted. Therefore I'd rather have humanity ask for an energy source, that would still eventually run out, but in the process would allow us to do great things that currently are not in our energy budget to perform. For example, obtaining lithium from the ocean - the expected amount of lithium in there is VAST, exceeding a megaton by orders of magnitude, so we only need to filter it out, This mostly required energy, everything else is more of a one-time investment. Lowering energy cost by increasing supply of the most energy-containing fuel known to humanity would thus eliminate the needs of most if not all commodities obtainable from this wizard.

**And a weird but still considerable desire (sarcasm)**

Request a wizard to provide as much as he possibly can of <sup>235</sup>U directly to the planet's core. The pressure down there would compact the uranium into a very supercritical blob that would just blow the planet apart with contained fission energy. No humans means perfect enonomy, huh?

Comment: Would containment be an issue to set up? Lead cells? How much Plutonium can be safely stored? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: This question ended up having a deep enough rabbit hole to consider changing the answer. Yet, apparently (239)PuO2 can be mass-stored as small enough spheres (1 kg or less) within externally cooled inert gas chambers, and processed afterwards to be converted into fuel cells. Yet its half-life wasn't as great (23000Y) as I expected, so asking for a megaton could be overkill, even if nuclear energy would proliferate on this supply. Storage maintenance would be an issue after some time of course, but initially existing exhausted nuclear storage facilities can be used to store all that Pu.

Comment: You have a problem with nuclear power in that only a few nations have access to it (32 countries operate nuclear plants according to Wikipedia), and the reasons more countries don't have access to it is more political than economic or the availability of the fuel.

Comment: @AmiralPatate well, politics aside, those 32 countries with nuclear energy are the majority of world economics, at least GDP wise. So if only those 32 countries get helped, the world economics will still get boosted at least 50% compared to something that could be globally utilized. But then, plutonium boost is expected to last a thousand years, what other material could you desire that would help for this long?

Comment: @AmiralPatate: And of those 32 countries, only a few can run Plutonium in their reactors. Most run on Uranium, due to nuclear proliferation concerns. Plutonium is closely associated with nuclear weapons infrastructure. Uranium comes in reactor-grade and weapons-grade; Plutonium is always weapons-grade.

Comment: Plutonium is a questionable choice due to it's use in nuclear weapons. Much better would be reactor grade uranium.

Comment: Are you sure that plutoniom produces clean and cheap energy? Remember that the most efficient economy in the world, Korea, has a nuclear industry which is 50 billion in debt, a huge net train on the world economy will result from your suggestion because plutonium only represents 2-3% of a nuclear power station building and operation.

Comment: The size and shape of each plutonium ball/disc/nugget/box is very important. Otherwise, BOOOOOOM, we are all dead!

Answer (score 7):

## Graphene

Graphene is the marvelous dream material from the future which already have a lot of applications. But also have a very big shortcoming: It is very hard to get any sizeable and usable good quality graphene sheet out of the lab (and even in the lab).

Real graphene is currently plagued by:

- Dislocations
- Grain boundaries
- Topological defects
- Impurities (like a nitrogen, an oxygen or a boron atom in the middle of the carbons)
- Isotopic impurities (carbon 13 and carbon 14 have a few noticeable differences than carbon 12).
- Wrinkles
- Buddings
- etc.

So, our best graphene labs should join their equipment and forces and work out how to create and provide the best ever graphene sheets that they can and use them as a sample.

### Where to dump all the graphene safely?

First, 3 millions of sheets of graphene have a millimeter of thickness.

Plant a 30 meters high pole in the middle of Sahara and ask Techno Mage Master Balmelgas to roll out a sheet of graphene around it until it reaches a radius of 10 km. This would provide us with a high quality graphene tape with a total area of...

$$\begin{align*}
\text{total graphene area} &= \frac{\text{volume of cillinder}}{\text{thickness of graphene}} \\
&= \frac{\pi \times \text{height} \times \text{radius}^2}{\text{thickness of graphene}} \\
&= \frac{\pi \times 30 \, \text{m} \times (10 \, \text{km}^2)}{\frac{1 \, \text{mm}}{3,000,000}} \\
&= \pi \times 30 \, \text{m} \times (10 \, \text{km}^2) \times \frac{3,000,000}{1 \, \text{mm}} \\
&= \pi \times 30 \, \text{m} \times (10 \times (10^3 \, \text{m})^2) \times \frac{3 \times 10^6}{10^{-3} \, \text{m}} \\
&= \pi \times 30 \, \text{m} \times (10 \times 10^6 \, \text{m}^2) \times 3 \times 10^6 \times 10^3 \times m^{-1} \\
&= 9\pi \times 10^{17} \, \text{m}^2 \\
&\approx 2,827,433,388,230.81388230814 \, \text{km}^2 \\
\end{align*}$$

This is a **HUGE** sheet of graphene coiled down in a single pole. In fact, if we were to cover the entire world with graphene, how much of the world we could cover with that much?

$$\begin{align*}
\text{coverage} &= \frac{\text{surface area of all that graphene}}{\text{surface area of Earth}} \\
&\approx \frac{2,827,433,388,230,81388230814 \, \text{km}^2}{510,072,000 \, \text{km}^2} \\
&\approx 5,543.2044657044775 \\
&\approx 5,543.2
\end{align*}$$

I.E. It would be enough to cover the entire world with high-quality pure graphene 5,543 times. And that with a single pole as the delivery location!

### Still not enough?

No problem! We can also plant billions of other many poles around the world, some might be shorter, some taller, they can be made of wood, iron, plastic, brick, cement, steel... whatever, they are nothing more than the places where the coiling will start. All we need to do is to ask for the great Techno Mage Master Balmelgas to coil all the graphene around them to different radii and different heights specific to each location as desired by each customer.

### What about carbon nanotubes?

Doable too, of course. We could get perfect nanotubes with thousands of kilometers in length. But their length and thickness vary a lot depending of the application. Length isn't really an issue, because it is easily solvable just by chopping it, but thickness very much is. Two carbon nanotubes of different thickness have very different applications.

I am unsure if Techno Mage Master Balmelgas would agree with also providing nanotubes of differing thickness. If he is, then that is great! But if he isn't, then ok, we already got the graphene sheets to work out and that is already at least half or three quarters of the hard work needed in order to produce carbon nanotubes of differing thickness.

Also, the delivery of nanotubes should be significantly different. Rolling out a single nanotube around a pole until it forms a disc of several meters thick and several kilometers in radius would make it several light-years long and really hard to unroll other than "let's just chop the entire disc", which would quite defeat the purpose for having a disc that size in the first place. However, the solution to that is simple: just provide a lot of nanotubes rolled to discs a few centimeters in radius around toothpicks instead, which is arguably far simpler.

Comment: Or carbon nanotubes - it is definitely going to be one of these difficult to make carbon structures. You could make a space elevator out of it and then use that to get all the other materials from asteroids.

Comment: @FelixB. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 5):

> [**Osmium**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmium) is the **densest naturally occurring element**. approximately twice as dense as lead

> Osmium is among the rarest elements in the Earth's crust, making up only 50 parts per trillion (ppt).[5][6] It is estimated to be about 0.6 parts per billion in the universe and is therefore **the rarest precious metal**.[7]

> Osmium is a hard but brittle metal that remains lustrous even at high temperatures. It has a **very low compressibility**. Correspondingly, its bulk modulus is extremely high, reported between 395 and 462 GPa, which **rivals that of diamond** (443 GPa). The hardness of osmium is moderately high at 4 GPa.[10][11][12] Because of its hardness, brittleness, **low vapor pressure** (the lowest of the platinum-group metals), and **very high melting point (the fourth highest of all elements**, after carbon, tungsten, and rhenium), solid osmium is difficult to machine, form, or work.

> **Only two osmium compounds have major applications**: osmium tetroxide for staining tissue in electron microscopy and for the oxidation of alkenes in organic synthesis, and the non-volatile osmates for organic oxidation reactions.

This is the element I'd like to see more of, if only so that we could try to do other things with it besides make fountain pens. It's a super toxic oxidant, and there's not enough to do anything with. Hopefully it won't just be the outer cases for iPhone 27s.

---

Next, there's **[rhodium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodium)**. I think we're all pretty tired of people stealing catalytic converters. But at the same time, this is why you can't just dump junk on the economy, or rather why you wouldn't if you owned mines:

> Owners of rhodium—a metal with a highly volatile market price—are periodically put in an extremely advantageous market position: extracting more rhodium-containing ore from the ground will necessarily also extract other much more abundant precious metals—notably platinum and palladium—which would oversupply the market with those other metals, lowering their prices. Since it is economically infeasible to simply extract these other metals just to obtain rhodium, the market is often left hopelessly squeezed for rhodium supply, causing prices to spike.

81% goes into catalytic converters; be neat to see what else a "corrosion-resistant transition metal" can do.

> Recovery from this supply-deficit position may be quite problematic in the future for many reasons, notably because it is not known how much rhodium (and other precious metals) actually was placed in catalytic converters during the many years when manufacturers' emissions-cheating software was in use. Much of the world supply of rhodium is obtained from recycled catalytic converters obtained from scrapped vehicles.

Comment: Osmium is not a good choice. It rapidly reacts with oxygen to produce the horrifically toxic gas osmium tetroxide. Merely being in the same room as a large enough sample of osmium without proper protection will land you in the hospital, if it doesn't kill you outright.

Comment: Enhancing electron microscopes and organic synthesis is a noble cause, but would it have a relevant impact on the world economy ? The question asks for "the most impact".

Comment: Being rare is not the same thing as being precious. Although osmium would have several very useful industrial, scientific and military applications if it were cheap and plentiful, its shortcomings other than scarcity also plays a major role.

Comment: "Essentially: carbon, osmium, tantalum, and tungsten, along with **rhenium** [#3 for my list], are the only (known, stable) elements that have *melting points high enough to remain solid* at the high temperatures required to achieve the colors of standard incandescent light bulbs." [Why can no other chemical elements be used for making a light bulb filament?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/741192/why-can-no-other-chemical-elements-be-used-for-making-a-light-bulb-filament)

Comment: "Only a few compounds of [rhenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhenium#Precautions) have been tested for their acute toxicity; two examples are potassium perrhenate and rhenium trichloride, which were injected as a solution into rats. The perrhenate had an LD50 value of 2800 mg/kg after seven days (this is very low toxicity, similar to that of table salt) and the rhenium trichloride showed LD50 of 280 mg/kg."

Answer (score 5):

## Think really, really big

1. How about dumping enough mass on mars so it can hold an atmosphere in the long term? At the moment it can not, due to its lack of an iron core which earth has.
2. How about a smaller star orbiting the solar system. Smaller stars burn slower, so it will be left over once our sun dies. Plus you could build a dyson sphere around it without making our sun darker

Comment: massing up mars is a good idea, downside adding that much mass will make mars uninhabitable for a few million years until it cools down.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there's no shortage of any material on Earth. We just sometimes lack in effective technologies to mine, absorb or process it.

If we take solar system, it can provide literally inexhaustible source of any material. Like trillions of tons of natural gas, just laying open on Titan, Saturn's satellite. But its hard to get it.
So, if I may guess, we (humanity) will get the most significant economy boost if we get something, providing us an opportunity to travel across space more effectively. I can think of 2 things.

1. carbon nanotubes. With really huge amount of nanotubes we can build space elevator, using modern technologies. If it passes the "structure" restriction nanotubes will be ultimate choice. If it doesn't then plan B.
2. Simply Uranium 238. Having enough Uranium the humanity can travel across and colonize solar system. We have already developed and ready to use nuclear drives, even multiple variants of design.

Of course, such an event like a powerful mage giving the humanity an enormous amount of any of these, will immediately start global civil war, because multiple bunches of capitalists all over the world will try to gain exclusive control over such a wealth, none of them even thinking of ordinary people's interests. That has to be taken into account.
So, your gift to humanity will 50/50 cause extinction of humanity or Communist revolution.

Comment: Carbon naotubes are acceptable. A sample of the material must nevertheless be provided. That will be replicated in the required quantity. If a 1mm long nanotube sample is provided then 1mm nanotubes is what is going to be given by Balmelgas. Not longer nanotubes. If a 5kg gold ingot is provided, that is what is going to be duplicated. Should I clarify this in question? I thought it was clear. Am not sure if it invalidates some of the answers

Comment: Please, DO NOT take into account the problems of equally sharing the material / benefits. That is outside the question and already clarified in the question. Let's just assume all governments will behave with enlighted self interest and share benefits equally. Besides, with someone as powerful as Balmelgas around would you risk upsetting him? He may come around again...

Comment: "Let's just assume all governments will behave with enlighted self interest and share benefits equally". They won't and never did. You, as a writer, definetely should at least provide a good explanation, why this all won't turn into global bloody massacre even before all that surplus material comes to earth.

Comment: Also, do we assume that Balmelga is willing to help humanity for some reason? May be his goal is to provoke such a massacre? For some social experiment or whatever?

Comment: that is OUTSIDE this question though. Just don't worry about it for the reply :)

Answer (score 3):

**Water, but in space.**

I love the ideas people are submitting about delivering something to space, which would really kickstart anything humanity might want to do in terms of building out a space program, but my proposal is "water". In space.

Water is very heavy. We need lots of it for any space programs. It's useful as radiation shielding too so if you can design your space ship to carry lots of water in tanks around the hull then you get the water you need for the trip plus radiation shielding all in one. But water being heavy means it's very expensive to bring up from earth.

Contract out some scientists to figure out if containment is needed and, if so, how, but I shouldn't think we need expensive containment (some flimsy solar shield maybe...or maybe it's better to just plop it all down on the moon as ice).

My thinking is that "space mining" can give us minerals we need, but lots of things (including generation of hydrogen for fuel, and oxygen) would be easy if we could start out with a big pile of water, either in orbit or readily available on the lunar surface. (We should be able to "mine water" in space but I think it's still a bit up in the air on how easy this will be. My understanding is that anything in the inner solar system has already had its water blasted away, unless it's buried. There is water on the moon, but getting it won't be as easy as just having a huge mountain of ice sitting there ready to go).

Comment: Water is not that heavy. Most metals are heavier.

Comment: You should also drop a hundred quadrillion tons or so on mars.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann My thinking is we can probably mine building materials in space. But water is oxygen, hydrogen (fuel/energy) and radiation shielding all in one and NASA seems a little dubious still about our ability to get large amounts of it in the inner solar system, short of launching it from Earth.

Comment: @blademan9999 that is interesting... what would happen? Mars would still be without a magnetic field.

Comment: @DuncanDrake I have read before that terraforming Mars would work fine if we could do it, despite the lack of magnetic field. The sun blows away the Martian atmosphere but it's such a slow process that if we could give it an atmosphere, it would take millions of years to blow it away. Top it off every couple hundred thousand years and it'll work out fine! Surface radiation might still be a problem, but it'll have at atmosphere at least. I bet covering it in enough water would be quite a lot of the terraforming needed.

Comment: @JamieB If you added a ludicrous amount of hot water (like, 1000km deep), it'd pull the temperature up too purely due to latent heat! Just don't disrupt the orbit.

Answer (score 3):

### On December the 21st 2022 Specifically: Fertilizer

Industrial fertilizer is a mixture of nitrate (NH3), potassium chloride (KCl), and Potash (P2O5) which on average doubles food output per acre.  The problem is that you need enough of all 3 of these elements to get a noticeable benefit and the trade embargos and cut-off supply lines caused by the Russian/Ukraine war have cut off many parts of the world from getting enough Potash and Nitrate.

Economists are predicting the following chain of evens in the next year or two as a result:

In many places in the world there will not be enough industrial fertilizer to sustain food production at the needed levels in 2023 which is estimated will lead to about a 25% reduction in global food production in the follow year.  Because of how necessary food is for survival, markets will compete aggressively to import enough food and fertilizer for basic survival.  The prices of agricultural products will increase several fold and drive down disposable income and demand for other goods and services causing many businesses less necessary for basic survival to collapse... which will lead to mass poverty and even bigger problems allocating food to the people who need it to survive.  As a result, millions of people will starve to death, and the damage to the world GDP both short term and long term could be massive.

.. the 3 element limit seems like a big problem here, but one that can be solved through cleaver chemistry.  Most of the world is still getting enough potassium chloride production; so, we can limit the problem to focusing on nitrate and Potash. While we can not request more than 3 elements, we could request a mixture of Nitrate(NH3) and White Phosphorous(P4).  We would have to have Balmelgas deposit this mixture into refrigerated rooms to keep it from exploding, but you could then separate the White Phosphorous from the Nitrate, and then burn the White Phosphorous.  The result of burning the Phosphorous is P2O5 which can then be recombined with the Nitrates and Potassium Chloride which you already have plenty of to make fertilizer.

Then the expected food crisis of 2023 could be mostly averted.  Literally millions of lives and jobs would be saved, and the global economy would have enough time to establish new fertilizer production facilities in new places to be able to meet the world's long term needs.

Whether or not this will yield the most dollar signs out of any possible substance is debatable, but I can guarantee that this is the one substance most world leaders will be able to agree is a top priority at this particular date.

Comment: I think you'll find that any real-life N-P-K fertilizer needs to have some oxygen, probably some carbon, and maybe some alkaline earths.  This would violate the limit to 3 elements.  Elemental phosphorus is particularly problematic.

Comment: @Theodore Ah, you are right, I totally brain farted and forgot that those are in fact Nitrogen, Potassium, and Phosphorus based compounds, revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: Scientifically, I think that fertilizer is the most common material in the atmosphere N2, the problem is trying to force it into the ground without NPK balance will not work, it will leach into the rivers, the fish will die, the lakes will bloom red and atrophy, the seashores will have huge freak marine growths, but yoru idea is super original other than that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haber_process this is a solved problem. I don't see how this would make an impact except for lower the price a tiny bit

Comment: @FelixB. The issue the world faces right now is a logistics issue, not a technological one.  The natural resources exist to fill the world's fertilizer deficit, but with supply lines being cut by the war, mean that it will take several years to build the new infrastructure to do so, but we need the fertilizer crisis to be solved in the next few months to stop the subsequent food shortages.  The key here is "Delivered material will be beamed directly in containment cells all over the world if such is the request."

Comment: 45% of the world's ammonia nitrate comes from Russia, and even more of it is made in Europe, but relies on Russian Natural gas in order to produce.  Russia also makes 20% of the world's Potash, but again logistics is the big problem here.  This does not mean that everyone will have 20% less Potash and 45% less nitrate, but that the Americas will continue to be fully supplied, whereas Europe will suffer a major nitrate shortage, and Africa and the Middle East will be short on both.

Comment: if it takes several years to build the logistic infrastructure, then that means there will also not be enough storage for the magic fertilizer to accept delivery, given that most supply lines try to minimize storage.

Comment: Tanks are easier to accommodate than whole refineries, especially right now.   Larger than normal numbers of grain, fertilizer, natural gas, and petroleum reserves silos are currently empty due to this last year's shortages. All you need to do is scrub them out and modify valves as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

**Sand**

Really a lot of pure Quartz sand (SiO$_2$) to be delivered to fragile coastal lines all over the planet, maybe also piled to new islands off-shore, and some large stashes of sand for use in construction in the hinterland.

There is already a shortage of good sand and thieves are stealing strands to use the sand for construction. So having an abundance of sand will be a good thing to the economy.

<sup>P.S. Realistic politicians will probably demand for some kind of fossile energy, with methane being to hard to contain, maybe some fluid like pure Octane or even something just solid like pure stearin. This will have positive short term effect (dampening inflation and making production of a lot of goods easier) but is bad in the long-term: More climate gasses, more greenhouse effect, and a deleterious effect on renewable energies). Sigh.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

### Put some Rocks in the Oceans!

Adding limestone land islands 10 times the size of Indonesia would do more for the planet than limitless energy. To do this, the magician has to change the protons and neutrons into different elements, rather than magically appear stuff through teleportation which is a bit low-tech for nursery books.

Land is a scarce commodity on the planet, forests are being decimated for food, animals are threatened by agriculture, humans are born without land and work all their lives to rent it. So magic 350 islands in the Atlantic and Pacific with 750 million cubic kilometers of basalt rock. We can add a land area the size of Africa to the ocean and use it to send the vices of humanity to a new place.

The condition to that is that the volume of water displaced is swapped or taken to the moon/mars and a new moon is created for mars to restart it's inner magnetic force.

Specifically which rock type, I dunno, perhaps porous limestone. Basalt is many chemicals. either way, adding a land area the size of Africa would do more for the planet than limitless energy.

Comment: No structures are allowed. What you will have is large dumps of the chosen material in the ocean. Displaced water is not going to be teleported anywhere, not part of the offer.

Comment: The addition of the material could happen over several days, so no big tsunami waves. But sea level is going to raise.

Comment: All this would do is transfer environmental destruction to the oceans and coastal and tidal parts of the world, along with destroying the climate of most of it. If you want to save the world, "magical continent appears!" is the exact opposite of helpful.

Comment: Well, actually, transmutation is a very good spell and it's easier than apparition from nowhere, because it just re-arranges the protons and atoms into different arrangements, like what happens in a stellar fusion, if you did that, you could actually replace the atoms of the ocean with a generous mix of other atoms of any kind you want because random transmutation is easier than purified transmutaiton of atoms.

Comment: @Nij, i'm a geoscientist and I agree but the pacific is one huge dead wasteland of salty low nutrient water, and the oceans actually have less biological life than the lands, so you would be creating a huge carbon sink for forests in a salty desert, and new habitats too. what i suggest is more scientifically based and realistic because it just requires a more magical ingelligence from the creator whereby the atoms of the ocean or whatever substance is being supplied are transmuted from one proton-neutron assembly to the other, and the atomic weight would be pretty similar...

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees "*...and the oceans actually have less **biological life** than the lands...*" - Well, what kind of life is non-biological? However, this is the exact site where such things might be considered...

Comment: I wrote biomass and then changed the wording:)

Answer (score 3):

### Platinum

Platinum isn't just a precious metal. It's extremely valuable as a catalyst for many oxidation/reduction reactions, and is highly treasured as the least reactive metal in existence.

Platinum is why people keep stealing catalytic converters. The lack of platinum catalysts is a limitation that prevents us from using fuel cell technology to replace batteries. There's a [lot of research](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-022-33892-8) right now on how to decrease the amount of platinum required by a fuel cell, simply because it's the cost-driving factor for that technology.

A sudden, wide-spread, massive dump of platinum would obviously cause the collapse of platinum prices, but there isn't a huge market for it to go bust due to its rarity. It would result in a massive boom in energy storage businesses, and allow the creation of cleaner power generation, and reduced energy costs. It would become the plating of preference for almost everything that you wanted to last a long time, especially lab equipment.

Answer (score 2):

## Oil

People are making very complicated answers involving space travel, advanced materials, and all sorts of things. But, there is something that is massively traded worldwide. There's something that caused wars worldwide. Oil.

You'd have to negotiate what range of chain lengths of hydrocarbon they will provide, but this is the most important resource. Our demand for goods based on oil is near infinite- plastics, fuels, medicines, drugs- and limited by price and supply.

The Ukraine war happened because Russia wanted Crimean gas. Many middle east conflicts have been over oil. If you have a basically infinite supply you can use it efficiently to produce huge amounts of goods and energy and valuable things. There are several reasons why it's the best commodity.

1. [Oil is the most traded commodity.](https://admiralmarkets.com/education/articles/general-trading/most-traded-commodities)
2. [It has a vast array of uses.](https://www.ukogplc.com/page.php?pID=74)
3. [It drives inflation and weaknesses in economies.](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/oilpricesinflation.asp)
4. [We can stop global warming with enough energy to capture carbon.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_capture_and_storage)

So yes, this is the most valuable commodity to ask for. Energy is what makes a civilization great, and oil is the most convenient chemical. If they demand one molecule, just ask for something like pentatriacontane. That can easily be cracked into whatever is needed.

Comment: "The Ukraine war happened because Russia wanted Crimean gas." - this is profoundly wrong. Russia wanted to secure its naval base at Sebastopol and its shrinking sphere of influence.

Comment: https://www.forbes.com/sites/arielcohen/2019/02/28/as-russia-closes-in-on-crimeas-energy-resources-what-is-next-for-ukraine/ wanting their gas is a widely commented on issue, especially since they ". When Russian forces annexed Crimea in 2014, they seized subsidiaries of Ukraine’s state energy conglomerate Naftogaz operating in the Black Sea. The Kremlin appropriated these companies — and billions of dollars of equipment — and delivered them to Gazprom, Russia’s state-owned energy giant. In one fell swoop, Russia ended Ukraine’s offshore oil and gas operations and bolstered its own."

Comment: Still, this is a side effect and not the underlying reason of war that is about spheres of influence. More on spheres of influence can be found in Samuel Huntington's *Clash of Civilizations* (published in 1996)

Answer (score 1):

***Food or Clean Water***

You guys are suggesting a lot of gold or steel, but it would be just better for humanity in general to get plenty of food or clean water.

Comment: "*the material must be simple. It can be a metal, a molecule, a polymer but no more that 3 elements in it. E.g. the molecule of Methane CH4 or Glucose C6H12O6 are admitted. Ammonium acetate NH4CH3CO2 is not.*" So food is out. Not to mention food rots so a massive store of it wouldn't do too much good for too long. Clean freshwater is possible but I'm guessing the places that need it most aren't going to be able to come up with a way to store enough of it in time. A massive glacier of fresh water does you little good if you're in a poor, drought ridden area.

Comment: And you can't ask for a *massive* glacier to be dropped right next door either because according to the question a small sample needs to be provided and *that* sample is what will be duplicated. Since we can't provide an entire glacier as a sample, it would be more like a sample of ice and in that case you need to be careful you don't suddenly dump a mountain-sized mound of avalanching ice or sudden snow into an area that can handle neither.

Comment: Yeah, it would have to be a limitless fountain (which is explicitly ruled out in the OP) to do any real good. Food or water resulting in short term human expansion is going to cause even more problems when it runs out.

Answer (score 1):

### Tell Techno Mage Master Balmelgas to take a hike!

This is a [Frame Challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609).

Introducing an abundance of *any material whatsoever* that could prove useful to either the environment or any form of industry or exchange would be ***devastating*** to the world economy. Whatever material you choose, there is a *massive* industrial complex behind it's acquisition, processing, distribution, use in manufacturing, more distribution, sales, consumption, and disposal. Providing an abundance turns all of that on it's proverbial ear.

Do you remember the movie *Chain Reaction?* The usual group of naive but well-intentioned scientists<sup>1</sup> build a technobabble-based free energy machine that they're ready to release to the world and the just as usual government Big Brother interference is trying to control and/or stop it. But the movie makes a very real and very good point. What happens when you dump too much of a resource onto the planet?

Markets crash. Nations collapse. People suffer.<sup>2</sup>

**Nature, including Humanity and all its raucous complexity and juvenile beliefs, is a struggle for balance**

And what too many people don't understand is that it's the *struggle* that's important, *not the balance.* Nature hates a balance just as it hates the proverbial vacuum.<sup>3</sup> Balances are bad because of *entropy.* If you stop pushing forward, "the universe" starts pushing you backward. Insofar as Humanity knows, there is no such thing (material, philosophy, whatever) that won't decay over time (entropy), and that means struggle... or die.

I can literally think of nothing Balmelgas could give us that would be a significant benefit that wouldn't be devastating. Maybe the cure to one minor disease. Maybe a box of snicker doodles.<sup>4</sup> Whatever it is, the gift must be (must be) *inconsequential* in the "Grand Scheme" of things or it will hurt rather than help.<sup>5</sup>

*So... thanks, Balmelgas. Here's the rose. Nice smell, are we right? There's the door. Don't let it hit you on the way out.*

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *Hollywood makes it seem like scientists and engineers can't understand economics. But as they say, the plot must go on.*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *And zombies. There's always zombies. Hollywood has convinced me that it doesn't matter what the cause is, the result is always zombies. I'm just sayin'... zombies.*</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> *RIP Leonard Nimoy.*</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup> *OK, maybe resurrecting Karen Carpenter. One of the most beautiful and talented singers to grace Earth. That wouldn't crash civilization — but it should.*</sub>

<sub><sup>5</sup> *To all you believers in Utopia and Post-Scarcity Civilizations... yeah. They can't exist. Not won't. Can't. It isn't simply the lack of a decision on Humanity's part or that we simply haven't earned enough wisdom yet. If that doesn't make sense, all I can say is you need another 10-15 years of life experience before you realize those are great Hollywood story foundations — and the worst possible prisons Humanity could force itself into. When the Wachowskis mentioned in The Matrix movies that humanity rejected perfection... that wasn't whimsical. That was insightful and based on thinking the issue through.*</sub>

Comment: This is where I think the "in space" answers are all an improvement. Putting a million tons of steel or titanium (or water) or whatnot into space means that any effort to go use it will have to involve an extensive, new space program. And bringing it down probably makes no sense -- you'd spend more landing and recovering most things than you'd earn using it. And building with it, in space, would be a wholly new industry, unlikely to compete with domestic uses.

Comment: @JamieB Possibly, by my sense of economics says it's not enough. The cost of pushing it into a decaying orbit with a predicted touch down and living with the burn-off and destruction that would cause is still almost infinitely less than the abundance. If the abundance is less than that, what's the point? Can you imagine what might happen if Big B changed Mars to host a breathable atmosphere and walked away? It's nice to think humanity would join together, sing a song, and use the planet wisely. The truth is it would start arms races and wars. Who controls the abundance?

Comment: My thinking is most things would be sufficiently destroyed by deorbiting them that you'd ruin the value (e.g. steel really has a low value per ton. Deorbiting enough to pay for the launch and effort would probably flatten some country and cause a nuclear winter.) Deorbiting water would be fairly pointless. Deorbiting gold would be worth it! So let's not ask for that. Water, though. Deorbiting it would be pointless, but its use in space for oxygen, fuel and actual water would be unprecedented value -- a kickstarter for a new industry (in space).

Comment: Utopia is a relative term. Some ancient people's might call how you're living utopic.

Comment: @fredsbend There are people living on the Earth today who might call my lifestyle utopic. But the folks who ask questions about achieving utopia on this Stack don't embrace that point of view.

Comment: @JBH I don't think you have evidence of that. In short, it's almost a strawman.

Comment: "all I can say is you need another 10-15 years of life experience before you realize those are great Hollywood story foundations — and the worst possible prisons Humanity could force itself into." I think that Neal Shusterman did a very good job of showing how this would work out in practice in his Arc of a Scythe trilogy.

Comment: @fredsbend According to Plato, utopia is when everybody's equally dirt poor.

Comment: @fredsbend You don't think I have evidence? Your 7 Qs/32 As on this Stack compared to my 54 Qs/1,246 As? It's like arguing with a 13 year old. Besides, you're complaining about one of my footnotes. You know that, right? Do you have a concern about my actual answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Petroleum**

Due to its high demand, Earth may get it. Sure, there may be problems with the oil companies, but hey, at least it will calm down those who freak out about running out.

Depending on its effect, it may even help make petroleum cheaper. If you are not looking for oil, then there is:

**Copper (or at least metals used in digital electronics**

Many of the metals used in our technology are either rare, come from dangerous mines, or both. If the aliens helped bring in these metals, we would have more access to the technology, maybe it might even cheapen. While of course, there will be problems with corporations and their own agenda, but for now, these are some simple ideas and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Trick question

**NOTHING**

Due to the laws of supply and demand, the more of something there are the more people can have that thing, thus demand goes down and so does the value of that thing.

It's why the Global Diamond market limits how many diamonds there are on the market (despite the fact that diamonds can be made in a lab fairly easily), it's to keep the demand (and thus, the price) up.

So, if we were to add a large amount of any material or resource, it would crash the global economy, not help it.

Comment: How about a material that is so scarce that there is no economy around it and yet so potentially useful?

Comment: @DuncanDrake depends on the resource and potential use, Antimatter is impossible to contain or even use in a controlled manner yet the potential market (mostly in the Aerospace, energy, and bomb-making parts of the economy) value is incredibly high. Usually, a material is rare because material physics deems it to be rare

Answer (score 1):

**Orthorhombic C8**

### A superstrong not-super-lubricious metastable carbon allotrope

Perfect long-fiber carbon nanotubes (in teratonne quantities, in orbit) might seem like a wonderful construction material, but a deep dive into the experimental literature shows why CNT are superstrong, but useless - defect-free carbon nanotubes are "superlubricious", practically zero friction.  There's no way to attach to perfect nanotubes, and imperfect nanotubes aren't much stronger than Dyneema and similar engineering fibers.

I recall a research paper about the construction of two *perfect* centimeter-long carbon nanotubes, a thinner tube nested inside a fatter tube - temporarily.  Since the tubes are practically frictionless, gravity is enough to slide the inner tube out of the outer tube.

Lattice defects on the tubes will stick to other lattice defects, but are also stress risers, weakening the tubes.  AFAIK, we will never build space elevators and similar magic structures with carbon nanotubes.

Computational atomic modelling to the rescue ... sorta.  While we don't know how to actually make the stuff, physicists have *computer simulated* a dense carbon crystalline material named "C-Centered Orthorhombic C8", which comes close to carbon nanotubes in strength, but has a repeating 3D structure.

The problem is that, though theoretically stable, the only way to form it is with pressures that can only be achieved with materials stronger than Cco-C8.  Or ultrahigh energy densities and luck. Or magic.

We could make 3D macroscopic structures with Cco-C8 - including attachment rings.  Start with a large crystal of Cco-C8, use an oxygen torch to carve out the finished product or device.  Subtractive processes, only Balmelgas has the additive magic which makes the material.

So, how do we make a tiny tiny sample?

Ultrahigh energy densities and luck - perhaps a hydrogen bomb blast in a carbon-lined cavern, followed by a LOT of molecular sorting to find
a microscopic chunk of Cco-C8 (among a zillion other carbon chunks) to give to Techno Mage Master Balmelgas.  However, with luck, we might achieve a similar microchunk with a LOT of shock tube chemistry ... and LOT of luck.

So, thousands of apparatus makers (the A team) build shock tubes QUICKLY, while the B team lines a cavern with carbon and sets off a low-fallout neutron bomb in it.   The rest of us are organized into microscope-wielding search teams to look at trillions of shock-compressed particles to find some lucky C8 particles.  WORK QUICKLY, time's a wasting!

We deliver our tiny crystal to Techno Mage Master Balmelgas, and say "please make a 0.02-Moon-scale crystal of this stuff, and park it at Earth-Moon L5."  A vastly larger crystal could be parked at Sun-Jupiter L5, but round-trip time to Earth would be long, and the escape velocity from such a large carbon crystal would be daunting.

---

Of course, in Real (fantasy) Life, most of the people of Earth would vote for an ocean of ethanol (harder drugs require nitrogen in addition to CHO).  Devout Muslims would vote against that, nuclear war would erupt over the decision, and we would all die.

Or, after all the effort and conflict, Balmelgas will say "just kidding".

---

Novel Superhard Carbon: C-Centered Orthorhombic
C8
Zhisheng Zhao, Bo Xu, Xiang-Feng Zhou, Li-Min Wang, Bin Wen, Julong He, Zhongyuan Liu, Hui-Tian Wang, and Yongjun Tian
Phys. Rev. Lett. 107, 215502 – Published 14 November 2011
https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.107.215502

Answer (score 1):

### Lithium-6

What's better than Lithium?
Lithium-6!
Lithium naturally occurs as 99% Li-7 and less than 1% Li-6.
As a result, Li-6 has 14% higher energy storage density (by weight) than lithium as we know it.

If received in megatonnes of elemental Li, you effectively get a load of energy for free too, as it arrives processed and 'charged'. But make sure you don't deplete the atmosphere of oxygen.

### Li-6 hydride or Li-6BH4

14% better than lithium? Rookie! Lets add loads of stored hydrogen with some wickedly exothermic release reactions. Hydrogen and heat both more or less pour out of this stuff. "Just add water". There are a million and one detailed hydrogen economy proposals based on either LiH or LiBH4. The main problem is that they never solve the problem of how to make the hydrides. Problem solved by this mage guy. LiBH4 is the densest energy storage material known to man; it just got 10% better by weight. It's also a very expensive but very useful chemical synthesis reagent.

### Li-6 fusion fuels

It gets better, though, because Li-6 is suitable as fusion fuel.

Get it either as Li-6-O-H-3 (Lithium-6 tritium oxide, fusion superfuel), or Li-6H-2H-3 (Lithium deuteride / lithium tritide mix).

### Choosing a form

If received in the elemental form, you get one immediate GDP boost (free energy/processed material), one medium term GDP boost (reusable energy storage material 14% better than we have now), and one long term boost (fusion fuel).

If received as the tritium oxide, the fusion future arrives decades sooner but the short term boost is smaller.

If received as the hydride or deuteride-tritide, you possibly get the best of both worlds.

Other alternatives to pure Li-6 include an unstable alloy with another element like iron and/or copper or rare earths (so you can easily process it to get all those elements), or Li-6 with He-3 bubbles.

My personal favourite: On balance, the lithium deuteride / tritide, with LiBH4 in second place.

Answer (score 0):

[Metallic Hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_hydrogen)

- Probably Room-temperature Superconductor (say hello to magnetically levitating everything without energy losses)
- Perfect Rocket fuel
- might not be metastable (i.e. not storable in which case this idea dies)

Comment: May you add details?

Comment: Explodes violently at any pressure you can achieve on earth...